# Git 'pull' showing conflict in a file, and file was not modified/changed

Tags: git, github

I have pull some changes in my branch and conflict arises in files that was not modified.

I have pull all changes from my **core** branch

```
git pull origin core
```

Then created a new branch from core **new-branch**

done some changes in **new-branch** and merge my core branch into new-branch for save side if there is any conflict then I 'll into **new-branch**

```
git merge core
```

Then I switched back to **core** branch

```
git checkout core
```

Again **pull** changes from **core**

```
git pull origin core
```

Then I tried to switch back to **new-branch** but git shows error that your local changes might be overridden you need to commit those changes, but I have't done any local change. Anyhow when I see the **git status** it shows all the modified files that was pulled, when I again execute the **git pull origin develop** command it shows some conflicts but I have done any change in those files.

Any idea why git show some conflicts **if we have pull twice**?

Comment: kth git this time behave very strange, before when I pull the changes each time git merge automatically, but this time not merged automatically and the the files in git status that was modified, and when I execute second time the pull command it shows the conflict and there noting conflicted code.

Comment: is `autocrlf` anything but "off"?

Comment: @mnagel: how can I check either its off or not?

Comment: `git config --global core.autocrlf` and `git config core.autocrlf`

Comment: What does `git status` and `git diff` tell you? Are you in the middle of a merge and have to resolve conflicts first?

Answer (score 0):

```
git reset HEAD  ## OR git reset HEAD --force
git pull
```

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/34444348)